# Thread and new counter

Tags: c#, multithreading, counter

How to correct the code that each newly launched thread use the new counter. At the moment when you start a new thread hangs the old, instead of going on.

Thanks for help.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        thread[counter] = new Thread(goThread);
        thread[counter].Start();
        counter++; 
    }

    private void goThread()
    {
            kolejka[counter] = new PictureBox();
            kolejka[counter].Location = new Point(325, n - 150);
            kolejka[counter].Image = threading.Properties.Resources.car;
            kolejka[counter].Size = new Size(20, 37);

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {

            this.Controls.Add(kolejka[counter]);
        });


        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                kolejka[counter].Location = new Point(kolejka[counter].Location.X, kolejka[counter].Location.Y - 3);
                this.Refresh();
            });
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Please do not deface your post after you have taken help from it. It is like cutting down a tree after taking shelter below it. Please allow the other future users to gain from the knowledge. The answerers would have put a lot of effort. Do not put their valuable time to waste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're increasing the `counter` variable, but it is used within your threads. Don't do that. In your case it is very important to make information local to the thread, because you want each thread to work on "its own" counter. This can be achieved like this:

```
private class ThreadInfo
{
    public PictureBox Picture;
    public int Counter;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    kolejka[counter] = new PictureBox();
    kolejka[counter].Location = new Point(325, n - 150);
    kolejka[counter].Image = threading.Properties.Resources.car;
    kolejka[counter].Size = new Size(20, 37);
    this.Controls.Add(kolejka[counter]);

    ThreadInfo info = new ThreadInfo() {
        Picture = kolejka[counter],
        Counter = counter
    };

    thread[counter] = new Thread(goThread);
    thread[counter].Start(info);

    counter++; 
}

private void goThread(object state)
{
    ThreadInfo info = state as ThreadInfo;

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            info.Picture.Location = new Point(info.Picture.Location.X, info.Picture.Location.Y - 3);
            this.Refresh();
        });
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

This does all the initialization stuff in your button event and passes in an instance of an info class. That info class takes all the information the thread needs, but so that it is local to the thread!

Comment: Thank you for your comment to my answer. Can you please comment, if it has sence to do what he has done on background thread? I mean he wants to move image in background thread. He changes coordinates on background thread, and to change picture location on the UI he should go to main thread back again.

Comment: Well, I can not really tell if it makes sense, as it is his project. But in any responsive application you have stuff running in the background and you at some point need to update the UI, so generally, yes, it does make sense to update UI stuff from background threads. If it is useful in this case or whether the same thing could be achieved using timers I can not say.

Answer (score 3):

Your old thread is not hanging. The problem is in your counter variable. It is shared by you threads. The old thread just continues on the `kolejka[counter]` of the new thread. I guess that is not what your want.

In the beginning of your goThread method you can do something like:

```
var item = kolejka[counter];
```

And then you can use item instead of kolejka[counter]. However this is not thread safe yet either, but a lot better then you have now.

Comment: Does it makes any sence to create a UI element on the other thread? I mean there should be overhead for creating in background thread for one PictureBox control with few properties, and then come back to main thread to draw it

Comment: The `counter` variable may be increased while the thread is started/ running. You should create a Event to wait on.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code.

- You use a variable `counter` without locking in two threads.
- Don't use arrays for this, because you don't have the `counter` value in control.
- Don't create controls on other threads than the gui thread.

For this purpose, you don't need threads. The easiest way is using one timer.

PSEUDO:

```
List<Car> _myCars = new List<Car>();

private Form1()
{
    _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.Interval = 50;
    _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var car in _myCars.ToArray())
    {
        car.Location = new Point(car.Location.X, car.Location.Y - 3);
        if(car.Location.Y < 0)
            _myCars.Remove(car);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _myCars.Add(new Car());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow up on **Peter**, you could create a copy at the beginning of the thread:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ManualResetEvent threadStartedSignal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    thread[counter] = new Thread(goThread);
    thread[counter].Start(threadStartedSignal);

    // wait for the thread to create a local reference.
    threadStartedSignal.WaitOne();
    counter++; 
}

private void goThread(object state)
{
    kolejka[counter] = new PictureBox();
    var myPictureBox = kolejka[counter];

    // signal the other thread, that the counter may be changed.
    ((ManualResetEvent)state).Set();

    myPictureBox .Location = new Point(325, n - 150);
    myPictureBox .Image = threading.Properties.Resources.car;
    myPictureBox .Size = new Size(20, 37);

    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        this.Controls.Add(myPictureBox );
    });


    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            myPictureBox.Location = new Point(myPictureBox.Location.X, myPictureBox.Location.Y - 3);
            this.Refresh();
        });
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```